# What is the maximum permissible length of android element id's?

Tags: android, android-layout

Working on a project where our element id's are getting long. Although we try and shorten them, the complexity of the application creates the situation of a long element id's in our layouts. So, what is the maximum length of android id elements ?

Comment: "...the complexity of the application creates the situation of a long element id's in our layouts"


What is your id naming convention? It sounds like you're being too verbose, especially since ids only need to be unique per layout.

Comment: @TimMalseed it's still manageable but typical id names are around 30-50 chars. The reason for the complexity is because of the type ahead feature in AndroidStudio. It presents all matching references to a particular element name regardless of which layout it comes from. Although initially convenient, when trying to identify specific layout ID's for an activity for fragment layout, it creates clutter when you're reusing an ID across multiple layouts.

Comment: Fair enough. Personally, I couldn't work with that kind of naming convention. I'd spend more time writing ids than searching for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML is not a problem, but as your IDs are part of `R` class when your project is build, and what would matter in such case are potential limits of Java language or compiler.

Java SE [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) says about this:

> Naming
>
> [...]
>
> Variable names are case-sensitive. A variable's name can be any legal
>   identifier — **an unlimited-length** sequence of Unicode letters and
>   digits [...]

But do not start the party yet, as when you dig deeper then you find "Java Virtual Machine Specification" document, which contains section with scary title [4.11. Limitations of the Java Virtual Machine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.11) which unveils:

> The length of field and method names, field and method descriptors,
>   and other constant string values (including those referenced by
>   ConstantValue (§4.7.2) attributes) is limited to 65535 characters by
>   the 16-bit unsigned length item of the CONSTANT_Utf8_info structure
>   (§4.4.7).

Still, "64K should be enough for everybody" :)

Comment: yes.. 64K should be more than enough..i was more concerned it was 64 characters or something like that. Although, I try and keep my element ID's below 64 chars!